# Moving/deleting data in cells without moving/deleting formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I am busy creating a production schedule in excel 2010. I have used formulas to give me due dates for each job and a check box for when the job are done. I used the following VB to move the information to sheet 2 when the check box is checked.

```
Sub MoveData()
  If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Check Box 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
     Range("A2:B2:C2:D2:E2:F2:G2:H2:I2:J2:K2:L2:M2").Select
     Selection.Cut
     Sheets("Sheet2").Select
     Range("A1").Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
     Range("A1").Select
  End If
End Sub
```

The problem I have now is that it moves the formulas with the details in the cells from sheet 1 to sheet 2. I need the formulas to be locked in sheet 1 and affect new information inserted into the cells. 
When the data in the row moves to sheet 2 the row is empty in sheet 1. Is there a way to automatically move all the remaining data up to fill the empty cells
Thanx

Comment: Do you want to copy the formulas for use in Sheet2? As in Sheet 1 says `=A2+B2`, when you copy that cell I assume it would update to `=Sheet1!A2+Sheet1!B2`, but you want it to stay as `=A2+B2` in Sheet 2?

Comment: No i don't need the formulas in sheet 2. Sheet 2 is just a record of jobs that are done. sheet 1 will be updated on a weekly basis so i need the formulas to stay in the cells so that when my boss ads new jobs and dates the formulas effect the new dates.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to copy the values from Worksheets(1) to Sheets("Sheet2")?

```
Sub MoveData()
    Dim r As Range

    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Check Box 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
        Set r = Worksheets(1).Range("A2:B2:C2:D2:E2:F2:G2:H2:I2:J2:K2:L2:M2")
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Resize(1, r.Count) = r.Value
        'r.ClearContents
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes i want the information in cell (job name, freight date) to be moved to sheet 2 but still have the formulas in sheet 1

Comment: The code above copies the values from Sheet1 to Sheet2 and preserves the formula on Sheet1.  This doesn't seem very useful.  Did you want to append the values of Sheet1 to the end of a list on Sheet2 instead?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cut and paste try the following.

```
Sub MoveData()
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Check Box 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
     Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:M1").Formula = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:M2").Formula
    Range("A1").Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Edit:
If you were cutting to remove the originals from Sheet1 just use,

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:M2").Clear
```

Comment: Thank you i will give it a try.